# React: How to switch active class in buttons group?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I got two buttons in group. Pressing any of the buttons makes it active and the other inactive. None of the buttons are pressed during the first boot up. Now when either button is pressed, both buttons become active. Can anyone help to fix it?

```
import cn from 'classnames';
import React from 'react';

class BtnGroup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { active: false };
  }

  onChangeClass = () => {
    const active = this.state.active;
    this.setState({ active: !active });
  };

  render() {
    const btnClass = cn({
      'active': this.state.active,
    });
    return ( 
      <div className="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" className={`btn btn-secondary left ${btnClass}`} onClick={this.onChangeClass}>Left</button>
        <button type="button" className={`btn btn-secondary right ${btnClass}`} onClick={this.onChangeClass}>Right</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "Now when either button is pressed, both buttons become active." That is because you share the same variable to assign a class to both buttons. To allow them to have separate state, you need separate variables for each button or logic that decides which button is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to differentiate which button you are clicking:

```
  onChangeClass = type => () => {
    this.setState({ active: type });
  };
```

and then in render:

```
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" className={`btn btn-secondary left ${cn({
      'active': this.state.active === 'left',
    })}`} onClick={this.onChangeClass('left')}>Left</button>
        <button type="button" className={`btn btn-secondary right ${cn({
      'active': this.state.active === 'right',
    })}`} onClick={this.onChangeClass('right')}>Right</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```